# How to add controls(i.e., label, checkbox) dynamically to tablerow directly in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to add controls(i.e., label, checkbox) dynamically to tablerow directly in c#

`tr.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "test" })`; is not working.

I dont want to add cell in row.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: @SLaks - I'm pretty certain that, whatever technology, tables usually consist of rows, which in turn consist of rows, which consist of content.

Comment: ASP.NET web application

Comment: @DavidKemp: That is usually true (although it's rather different in WPF), but it doesn't help answer the question.  (also, I assume you mean cells)

Comment: @DavidKemp: rows within rows hey? I think you've been watching one too many Leonardo DiCaprio films

Comment: @musefan table -> row -> cells. the sun's past the yard arm ;)

Answer (score 0):

Does the table and table row have `runat="server"` set so that they are accessible within the code behind?  If not, that is the issue as there is the question of how is the page supposed to link these things together.

Answer (score 0):

An HTML `<tr>` element cannot render content.  A table row must contain a table cell.  Per the [HTML 4.01 Specification, Section 11.2.5](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.5)

*"The TR elements [sic] acts as a container for a row of table cells. The end tag may be omitted."*